# neural network training set

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

My question is about a training set in a supervised artificial neural network (ANN)

Training set, as some of you probably know, consists of pairs (input, desired output)

Training phase itself is the following

```
for every pair in a training set

-we input the first value of the pair and calculate the output error i.e. how far is the generated output from the desired output, which is the second value of the pair

-based on that error value we use backpropagate algorithm to calculate weight gradients and update weights of ANN 

end for
```

Now assume that there are `pair1, pair2, ...pair m, ...` in the training set

we take `pair1`, produce some error, update weights, then take `pair2`, etc.

later we reach `pair m`, produce some error, and update weights,

My question is, what if that weight update after `pair m` will eliminate some weight update, or even updates which happened before ?

For example, if `pair m` is going to eliminate weight updates happened after `pair1`, or `pair2`, or both, then although ANN will produce a reasonable output for input m, it will kinda forget the updates for `pair1` and `pair2`, and the result for inputs 1 and 2 will be poor,
then what's the point of training?

Unless we train ANN with `pair1` and `pair2` again, after `pair m`

Answer (score 3):

> For example, if pair m is going to eliminate weight updates happened after pair1, or pair2, or both, then although ANN will produce a reasonable output for input m, it will kinda forget the updates for pair1 and pair2, and the result for inputs 1 and 2 will be poor, then what's the point of training ??

The aim of training a neural network is to end up with weights that give you the desired output for all-possible input values. What you're doing here is traversing the error surface as you back-propagate so that you end up in an area where the error is below the error threshold. Keep in mind that when you backpropagate the error for one set of inputs, it doesn't mean that the neural network automatically recognizes *that particular* input and immediately produces *the exact response* when that input is presented again. When you backpropagate, all it means is that you have changed your weights in such a manner that your neural network will get *better* at recognizing that particular input (that is, the error keeps decreasing).

So if you present pair-1 and then pair-2, it is possible that pair-2 may negate the changes to a certain degree. However in the long run the neural network's weights will tend towards recognizing all inputs properly. The thing is, you cannot look at the result of a particular training attempt for a particular set of inputs/outputs and be concerned that the changes will be negated. As I mentioned before, when you're training a neural network you are traversing an error surface to find a location where the error is the lowest. Think of it as walking along a landscape that has a bunch of hills and valleys. Imagine that you don't have a map and that you have a special compass that tells you in what direction you need to move, and by what distance. The compass is basically trying to direct you to the lowest point in this landscape. Now this compass doesn't know the the landscape well either and so in trying to send you to the lowest point, it may go in a slightly-wrong direction (i.e., send you some way up a hill) but it will try and correct itself after that. In the long run, you will eventually end up at the lowest point in the landscape (unless you're in a local minima i.e., a low-point, but one that is not the *lowest* point).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you're doing supervised training, you should run several (or even thousands) rounds through a training dataset. Each such round through the training dataset is called an *epoch*.

There is also two different ways of updating the the parameters in the neural network, during supervised training. **Stochastic training** and **batch training**. Batch training is one loop through the dataset, accumulating the total error through the set, and updating the parameters (weights) only once when all error has been accumulated. Stochastic training is the method you describe, where the weights are adjusted for each input, desired output pair.

In almost all cases, where the training data set is relatively representative for the general case, you should prefer stochastic training over batch training. Stochastic training beats batch training in 99 of 100 cases! (Citation needed :-)). (Simple XOR training cases and other toy problems are the exceptions)

Back to your question (which applies for stochastic training): Yes, the second pair could indeed adjust the weights in the opposite direction from the first pair. However it is not really likely that all weights are adjusted opposite direction for two cases. However since you will run several epochs through the set the effect will diminish through each epoch. You should also randomize the order of the pairs for each epoch. (Use some kind of Fisher-Yates algorithm.) This will diminish the effect even more.

Next tip: Keep a benchmark dataset separate from the training data. For each n epoch of training, benchmark the neural network with the benchmark set. That is calculating the total error over the pairs in this benchmark dataset. When the error does not decrease, it's time to stop the training.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you were performing a stochastic gradient descent (SGD), then this probably wouldn't happen because the parameter updates for pair 1 would take effect before the parameter updates for pair 2 would be computed.  That is why SGD may converge faster.

If you are computing your parameter updates using all your data simultaneously (or even a chunk of it) then these two pairs may cancel each other out.  However, that is not a bad thing because, clearly, these two pairs of data points are giving conflicting information.  This is why batch backprop is typically considered to be more stable.

Comment: thanks for comment, but to tell the truth, so far I've never heard about parameter updates to use all data, or chunk of it, simultaneously : ) Is this a popular strategy ?

Comment: Yes, I would say it is a very popular strategy; probably more popular than SGD.  They have different optima b/c they are not using the **true** gradient but are using an approximation of it: an approximation created by adding all the gradients together.